# Forecast a trendline of a periodic time series

Tags: c#, excel, forecasting

I have some data in an Excel spreadsheet, which represents a bunch of date-times where samples have been taken. The dates are increasing linearly but there are some periodic gaps (leading to discontinuities in the date-data).

See the attached image as this shows the periodic nature of the data. Notice the rate of change shows clear spikes where discontinuities occur.

[image]

The data is a single column in an Excel spreadsheet of DateTimes. I would like to forecast this repeating series into the future so as to make estimates of future discontinuities.

Ultimately I want to code this in C# but if anyone has an idea of an algorithm that can perform such a forecast, either in Excel, or C#/C it would be great!

I thought about Auto-Correlation however can't figure out how to do that in Excel to test it.

Comment: a) you need to compute the rate of change for independent variable, i.e. time, not the measured values [even if they are ploted on x-axis, it is still the dependent variable, i.e. f(x)] + b) are there always 3 levels of rate of change (e.g. every day increase by 0, every week increase by 0.7, every month increase by 2.7) or **what is the most-generalizable pattern** here?

Comment: The rate of change graph is the difference of the time-value from one sample to the next. The most generalizable pattern is as follows. The data is time-stamps from futures prices. The time-stamps have a small discontinuity overnight (4 nights a week) as the market is closed. The time-stamps have a larger discontinuity over weekends or trading holidays. For some instruments the time-stamps are at regular intervals however for others they are more irregular which compounds the issue. Your thoughts welcome :)

Comment: if the data are exactly linear per-calendar-day basis, then the chart is not a fair representation of the data - why do you use it???

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by this

Comment: if you would fill the gaps, would the data series be a straight line without jumps??

Comment: In some cases yes, it would be a straight line, e.g. timestamps are every 15 minutes. However in other cases they vary, e.g. timestamps can be 5mins, 6mins, 3.4mins, 5mins. Also regarding date-gaps, the point is I want to predict the gaps into the future where they can be irregular usink the known data. Some markets have overnight gaps of 16 hours, others 4 hours. Some markets have intraday gaps of 30 minutes. Some have 2 day weekends, some 1 day weekends etc...

Comment: i see - you need to predict both dates and values - these are 2 different tasks, i'll update my answer to include predicting dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to explain my comments about correct data representation:
[image]

if the data can be represented by a linear function, i.e.:

```
f(date) = start_value + daily_increase * (date - fist_date)
```

then you can do a simple linear regression - in my excel example use this [LINEST function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/linest-HP005209155.aspx) (entered in 2 cells at the same time as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=LINEST(C2:C31;A2:A31)
```

the results (6, -220436) are linear and constant factors of a linear regression formula:
=> `f(date) = 6 * date - 220436`

Comment: Ok - I see what you mean by representation of the data. The question should be clearer. 

The X,Y values in the graph I presented are X=sample number (linearly increasing) and Y=DateTime. What I am trying to estimate is the DateTime for a sample number in the future. E.g. I have samples 1-120 in my test data. What is the estimated date for unknown sample 140?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I got it - thanks for the input, especially on Excel Linest function and how to use it :)

Comment: just to be crystal clear about my choice of X and Y values - the time won't turn back if the prices start falling

Answer (score 1):

in case someone needs a cyclic data generator, use this algorithm (excel formula):

```
=baseline_value
 + INT([@Step]/repeat_c1) * increase_c1
 + INT([@Step]/repeat_c2) * increase_c2
 + INT([@Step]/repeat_c3) * increase_c3
 ...
```

to compute the increases, the cycles need to be ordered from the shortest to the longest - see an illustration for this cycle specification:

1. every step, increase the previous value by 2 hours
2. for every 2nd step, increase the previous value by 22 hours instead of 2 (i.e. by additional 20)
3. for every 8th step, increase by 70 hours (additional 48)

[image: test of cyclic data generator]